# Checked radio that is insert in database when select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Assuming this that we in time insert data in database has 3 `input:radio` and with select one from they, insert value it to database. now how in select from database same radio that inserted in database, is checked.

Example:
We have 3 `input:radio` as:

```
<input type="radio" name="type1" value="value1">
<input type="radio" name="type2" value="value2" checked>
<input type="radio" name="type3" value="value3">
```

With checked `value2` inserted it in database, now we want show(`select`) all radios and checked it radio that is inserted to database.as(this is after select from database):

```
<input type="radio" name="type1" value="value1">
<input type="radio" name="type2" value="value2" checked> // this value was in the database
<input type="radio" name="type3" value="value3">
```

How can fix it with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, as alreay said, use the same name for the radio buttons. Also, the right sintax is `checked="checked"` :

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="value1">Value 1
<input type="radio" name="type" value="value2" checked="checked">Value 2
<input type="radio" name="type" value="value3">Value 3
```

When retrieved from database, you can check if value equals to the one in your html, and set a checked attribute accordingly.

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="value1" <?php echo ($query_hs->type == 'value1') ? 'checked="checked"' :'';?>>Value 1
<input type="radio" name="type" value="value2" <?php echo ($query_hs->type == 'value2') ? 'checked="checked"' :'';?>>Value 2
<input type="radio" name="type" value="value3" <?php echo ($query_hs->type == 'value3') ? 'checked="checked"' :'';?>>Value 3
```

Just substitute your own values with my standard one, like:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="hotel" <?php echo ($query_hs->type == 'hotel') ? 'checked="checked"' :'';?>>Hotel
```

Comment: I use from it as:`<?php $query_hs->type == 'hotel' ? echo 'checked="checked"' :'';?>`, but have error:`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in...`

Comment: @Emmy Charles God, I'm sorry, it's morning here I'm still asleep. I corrected my code, echo was in the wrong position, sorry!

Comment: Is `$query_hs->type` really 'hotel'?

Comment: yes, this worked: `<?php if($query_hs->type == 'hotel') echo'checked="checked"';?>` but your code not worked !!?

Comment: My code is a shorthand for that. I'll update to reflect your vars naming

Answer (score 0):

First of all, name of the radio element should be same for all three radio buttons so that they form a group.  Otherwise, your users will be able to select all three.

Second, define the set of values as array in PHP.  And run a forloop to generate HTML code.  Something on these lines -

```
<?php
$radio_values = array("value1", "value2", "value3"); // Assuming your set of values is static

foreach($radio_values as $value) {
    $value_from_db = read_radio_value();      // Replace this with your logic to fetch values from database
    if ($value_from_db == $value) $checked = "checked";
    else $checked = ""; 
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"type\" value=\"{$value[$i]}\" {$checked}>";  
}
?>
```

Comment: Did it not better with `foreach`?How is it?